# Problems trying to create multiple Frame Buffer Objects in OSX but not Linux

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm writing an applications that contains a collection of small scatter plots (called `ProjectionAxes`). Rather then re-render the entire plot whenever new data is acquired I have created a texture and render to that texture and then render the texture to a quad.  Each plot is an object and has its own texture, render buffer object, and frame buffer object.

This has been working great under Linux but not under OSX.  When I run the program on Linux each object creates its own texture, FBO, and RBO and everything renders fine. However when I run the same code on OSX the objects do not generate separate FBOs but appear to all be using the same FBO.

In my test program I create two instances of `ProjectionAxes`. On the first call to `plot()` the axes detect that the textures haven't been created and then generates them. During this generation process I display the integer values of the textureId, RBOid, and FBOid. When I run my code this is the output I get when I run the program under Linux:

```
ProjectionAxes::plot() --> Texture is invalid regenerating it!
Creating a new texture, textureId:1
Creating a new frame buffer object fboID:1 rboID:1
ProjectionAxes::plot() --> Texture is invalid regenerating it!
Creating a new texture, textureId:2
Creating a new frame buffer object fboID:2 rboID:2
```

And for OSX:

```
ProjectionAxes::plot() --> Texture is invalid regenerating it!
Creating a new texture, textureId:1
Creating a new frame buffer object fboID:1 rboID:1
ProjectionAxes::plot() --> Texture is invalid regenerating it!
Creating a new texture, textureId:2
Creating a new frame buffer object fboID:1 rboID:2
```

Notice that under linux the two FBO's have different IDs, whereas under OSX they do not.
What do I need to do to indicate to OSX that I want each object to use its own FBO?

Here is the code I use to create my FBO:

```
void ProjectionAxes::createFBO(){
    std::cout<<"Creating a new frame buffer object";//<<std::endl;

    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &fboId);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &rboId);

    // Generate and Bind the frame buffer
    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fboId);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fboId);

    // Generate and bind the new Render Buffer
    glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &rboId);
    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, rboId);

    std::cout<<" fboID:"<<fboId<<" rboID:"<<rboId<<std::endl;

    glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, texWidth, texHeight);
    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    // Attach the texture to the framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, rboId);

    // If the FrameBuffer wasn't created then we have a bigger problem. Abort the program.
    if(!checkFramebufferStatus()){
        std::cout<<"FrameBufferObject not created! Are you running the newest version of OpenGL?"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"FrameBufferObjects are REQUIRED! Quitting!"<<std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}
```

And here is the code I use to create my texture:

```
void ProjectionAxes::createTexture(){

    texWidth = BaseUIElement::width;
    texHeight = BaseUIElement::height;

    std::cout<<"Creating a new texture,";
    // Delete the old texture
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textureId);
    // Generate a new texture 
    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    std::cout<<" textureId:"<<textureId<<std::endl;
    // Bind the texture, and set the appropriate parameters
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE); 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    // generate a new FrameBufferObject
    createFBO();

    // the texture should now be valid, set the flag appropriately
    isTextureValid = true;

}
```

Comment: Why are you deleting `FBOs` in the `createFBO` function?

Comment: great question, if the window is re-sized then I declare the textures as invalid and create new resized textures, rbos and fbos. I then delete the previously used texture, FBO, and RBO. The docs I found said there aren't any problems with deleting an object that doesn't already exist so i call delete before generate.

Comment: I would try and temporarily comment out the `glDelete*` calls (yes, this will leak), and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't you're doing something strange with the handles.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck that fixed the issue, can you post that as a answer so I can accept it? Additionally if I create a new texture can I simply bind that texture in the old frame buffer or do I have to create a new frame buffer as well?

Comment: I don't remember, you'll have to try it out :)

Comment: @slayton: You don't have to delete OpenGL objects if you're reusing their IDs. Just reinitialize them with the new data.

Comment: @datenwolf: That is a bad idea. And impossible if you use [`glTexStorage*`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Texture_Storage) for your textures. Yes, it's possible to do so, but I would expect better driver behavior from delete-then-recreate patterns. That's what is more commonly used.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't see a problem if the storage layout remains the same. Which is most likely the case with render-to-textures. And in the case of FBOs there's actually no storage layout asociated with the FBO itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and temporarily comment out the `glDelete*` function calls. You're probably doing something strange with the handles.